# Resize google maps in swift 3

Tags: google-maps, swift3

I am using swift 3, I added googlemaps from storyboard and I trying to resize the maps Height by two ways but it didn't work :

```
googleMapsView.frame = CGRect(x : self.googleMapsView.frame.origin.x, y : self.googleMapsView.frame.origin.y, width : self.googleMapsView.frame.width, height : 10 )

self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x self.googleMapsView.frame.origin.x, y : self.googleMapsView.frame.origin.y, width : self.googleMapsView.frame.width, height : 10 ), camera: googleMapsView.camera)
```

I hard code Height equals 10 for test.

How can I do to change this height?

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have used Autolayout and therefore constraints to define the size of your map view. If you want to change its height programmatically, create an IBOutlet into your holding view controller and set its constant property to the desired height.

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapsHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    googleMapsHeightConstraint.constant = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

- Remove all googleMapsView constraint from storyboard
- Add Constraint by coding

> ```
> googleMapsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewHeader.bottomAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
> googleMapsView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
> googleMapsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
> googleMapsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
> googleMapsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
> ```